# Heterogenous vectors of pointers. How to call functions

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I would like to create a heterogeneous structure to store pointers to some classes so that I can loop through it and call a write() function.

The idea is this:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <vector>

template< typename T>
class A
{
    public:
        A(){}
        ~A(){}

        void write();

    private:
        T data;
};

template< typename T>
void A<T>::write()
{
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   A<int> one;
   A<double> two;

   typedef boost::variant<A<int>*, A<double>* > registry;
   std::vector<registry> v;


   v.push_back(&one);
   v.push_back(&two);

   for(unsigned int i =0; i< v.size(); i++)
   {
       v[i]->write();
   }

}
```

However, this code does not compile. Showing the error:

```
error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<boost::variant<A<int>*, A<double>*> > >::value_type {aka boost::variant<A<int>*, A<double>*>}’
         v[i]->write();
```

How can I fix this? I would also appreciate ideas on the implementation

Comment: You are mixing multiple things here. Either you should use pointers (smart pointers preferably) and virtual functions. Or you can use `std::variant/std::any` and use `std::visit`. Using a variant with pointers to non-virtual classes seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Another approach is polymorphism: `A<T>` inherits from `struct Base { virtual void write() = 0; /*..*/ };` and then `std::vector<Base*> v{&one, &two};` and your loop would work.

Comment: I've posted my answer at your follow-up question https://stackoverflow.com/a/69944947/85371

Comment: @Jarod42, that is also viable. Make it inherent from a pure virtual class and have a common base class.

Answer (score 1):

`v[i]` returns a `boost::variant<A<int>*, A<double>*>` instead of a pointer to an instance of `A`, so you cannot use `operator->` on it. You need to use `boost::apply_visitor` to visit the content fo the variant.

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
  boost::apply_visitor([](auto a) { a->write(); }, v[i]);
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/reaKczK6c)

Since lambda uses auto as a parameter type is a feature of C++14, in C++11, you need to create a callable class with a template `operator()` as the visitor, as shown below:

```
struct Visitor {
  using result_type = void;
  template<typename T>
  result_type operator()(A<T>* a) const { a->write(); }
};

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
  boost::apply_visitor(Visitor{}, v[i]);
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/4Y1qdEcoP)

Comment: This only works with c++14. It there any variation for c++11?

Comment: @ManuelOliveira instead of the `auto` parameter, you can write two functions, one for A<int> and one for A<double>, or you can write a functor whose operator() is a template. Note that either way, you're either writing two different functions or getting the compiler to write them for you, because A<int> and A<double> are completely unrelated types.

Comment: @ManuelOliveira. Updated, see my latest answer.

Comment: @康桓瑋. I do not know if the heterogeneous vector to store the data is a good approach. But I am quite impressed with your answer! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answer I built:

```
class myVisitor
: public boost::static_visitor<>
{
    public:
        template< typename T>
        void operator() (A<T>* a) const
        {
            a->write();
        }
};
```

And use it in the code as:

```
for(auto x: v)
{
    boost::apply_visitor(myVisitor(), x);
}
```

Or with a common base class as:

```
class tst
{
    public:
        virtual ~tst() {}
        virtual void write() = 0;
};

template< typename T>
class A : public tst
{
    public:
        A(){}
        ~A(){}

        void write();

    private:
        T data;
};

int main()
{
   A<int> one;
   A<double> two;

   std::vector<tst*> v;


   v.push_back(&one);
   v.push_back(&two);

    for(auto x: v)
    {
       x->write();
    }
}
```

What do you think?